# how to encode image from mysql in style='background-image' tag

Tags: php, mysql, image

this is my code
instead of image it is showing random numbers

```
    <?php
    while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($show)){
    echo "<div class='post' style='background-image: url(\"data:base64;base64.$res[image]\").'>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must encode the image source in base64, with the PHP's [`base64_encode`](https://php.net/base64_encode) function.

```
$base64image = base64_encode($res['image']);
echo "<div class='post' style='background: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,$base64image);'>";
```

Note that the `url` argument specify `image/jpeg` but you must change it accordingly to your image type.